# How to create a Junit test for the following controller?

Tags: rest, junit, spring-test

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @PostMapping(value="/update-details")
    public String updateDetails(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,@RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,@RequestParam("email") String email, 
            @RequestParam("userName") String username, @RequestParam("phoneno") String phoneno, Principal principal) 
    {
        String user = principal.getName();

        User currentUser = this.userRepo.getUserByEmail(user);

        currentUser.setFirstName(firstName);
        currentUser.setLastName(lastName);
        currentUser.setPhoneno(phoneno);
        currentUser.setEmail(email);
        currentUser.setUserName(username);
        this.userRepo.save(currentUser);

        
        return "redirect:/index";

    }
}
```

Can I please get some as to how I can test this controller through Junit? I am fairly new to web development and would like to know how I can create a test

Comment: I think you are missing the point of using stack overflow. I recommend readind [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . There are plenty of resources out there which can help you understand Junit and how to get started with it.

Comment: This [MockMv](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) guide can help you understand what & how to test it.